# How can i search in a select statement by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I'm working on a website and one of the features for the admin is connection a client to a code.

I have written a code in using MVC to get all the users from the database and sets them as options. Now i need i search bar so i can select a name.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <select name="userID" id="userID">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <option> @Model[i].Username @Model[i].Email</option>
        }
    </select>
    <button onclick="getUsersFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <a ondrag="onClickFunction()"> @Model[i].Username @Model[i].Email</a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css code

```
.dropbtn {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
background-image: url('searchicon.png');
background-position: 14px 12px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
font-size: 16px;
padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
border: none;
 }

.dropdown {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f6f6f6;
min-width: 230px;
overflow: auto;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

and the javascript codes

```
function getUsersFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
}
```

the searching part works but the are not combined yet and i dont know how.

Comment: You should use PHP

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to reach... and what is your `onClickFunction()`

Comment: i was hopping with that function to insert the selected item in the select tag.

Comment: selected item of what ? Sorry  i am not able to understand what you are trying to do (Your expected output)

Comment: i have a list of users in my model. these are my items. and with a search bar i want that item as selected item .